# Gradle package multiple Spring MVC projects into a single war

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, war

I have two spring mvc projects and struts project(ignore for now). I am using servlet 3.1 java config to initialize my applications context. 
Both projects run individually by applying gretty plugin.
i.e

http://localhost:8080/project-1/

http://localhost:8080/project-2/project2  (notice servlet mapping in project-2 config)

What I have tried so far.
Gradle multi project

```
rootproject
    |
    |-project-2
    |  src
    |  |-main
    |      |-java
    |      |    |-controllers
    |      |    |-config
    |      |
    |      |-webapp
    |--build.gradle
    |
    |-project-2
    |  src
    |  |-main
    |      |-java
    |      |    |-controllers
    |      |    |-config
    |      |
    |      |-webapp
    |--build.gradle
    |
    |-build.gradle
    |-settings.gradle
```

rootproject build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }

}
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8


    eclipse {
        classpath {
            containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
            containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
        }
    }

}
```

settings.gradle 
    include 'project-1','project-2'

project-1 config

```
//WebServlet  java config
public class WebServletConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webCtx.register(SpringConfig.class);
        webCtx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

  }

}
```

project-1 build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // .. all required dpendencies
}
```

project-2

```
//WebServlet  java config
public class WebServletConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webCtx.register(SpringConfig.class);
        webCtx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/project2/*");

  }

}
```

project-2 build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // .. all required dpendencies
}
```

What I want to achieve:

Both projects packaged into single war file.

and url as

http://localhost:8080/rootproject (project-1 here)

http://localhost:8080/rootproject/project2 (project-2 here)

Comment: for god sake use maven..its easier and better

Comment: can i achieve this using maven?

Comment: are you using tomcat for deployment , then it can directly deploy to tomcat webapps folder , both war

Comment: Yes I'm using tomcat and I want to integrate a springboot project as project 2.